# Expecting function body despite it being provided

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance

I have a base class called `Node` which defines two functions: `indent` and `toString`. The former will be used by all derived classes without overriding, however the latter will be overridden in the derived classes.

*Node.hpp*

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Node {
    public:
        virtual std::string toString(int level) const {};
        std::string indent(int level);
};

#endif
```

*Node.cpp*

```
#include "Node.hpp"

std::string Node::indent(int level) {
    std::string indt;
    for(int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        indt += "\t";
    }
    return indt;
}
```

I have a derived class `FunctionNode` which wants to override `toString` in `node.hpp`.

*FunctionNode.hpp*

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_NODE_H
#define FUNCTION_NODE_H

#include "TypeNode.hpp"
#include "ParamsNode.hpp"
#include "BlockNode.hpp"
#include "DeclarationNode.hpp"

class FunctionNode : public DeclarationNode {
    std::shared_ptr<TypeNode> type;
    std::string name;
    std::shared_ptr<ParamsNode> paramList;
    std::shared_ptr<BlockNode> block;

    public:
        FunctionNode(std::shared_ptr<TypeNode> type,
                const std::string &name,
                std::shared_ptr<ParamsNode> paramList,
                std::shared_ptr<BlockNode> block)
            : type(std::move(type)), name(name),
                paramList(std::move(paramList)), block(std::move(block)) {}
};

#endif
```

Note that `DeclarationNode` is derived from `Node`.

*FunctionNode.cpp*

```
#include "FunctionNode.hpp"

std::string FunctionNode::toString(int level) const override {
    std::string indt = indent(level);
    std::string s = indt + "FunctionNode\n"; 
    s += type->toString(level + 1);
    s += indt + "\t" + name + "\n";
    s += paramList->toString(level + 1);
    s += block->toString(level + 1);
    return s;
}
```

When I try to compile *FunctionNode.cpp* to an object using the following line in my Makefile.

```
FunctionNode.o: FunctionNode.cpp FunctionNode.hpp TypeNode.hpp ParamsNode.hpp BlockNode.hpp
```

I get the following error.

```
FunctionNode.cpp:3:55: error: expected function body after function declarator
std::string FunctionNode::toString(int level) const override {
                                                      ^
```

But I have provided the function body. How do I fix this error?

Comment: I don't see a declaration for `FunctionNode::toString` in the definition of `FunctionNode` in `FunctionNode.hpp`.

Comment: Which C++ version are you compiling for? Also, is all that code really necessary (IOW, is it a [mcve])?

Comment: I thought that since I am overriding toString I didnt have to declare it again. @NathanPierson

Comment: No, you still need to declare virtual functions that you're overriding.

Comment: How would I do this? Like this: std::string toString(int level) const override {};

Comment: Drop the `{}` at the end so you can put the delcaration in `FunctionNode.hpp` and the definition in `FunctionNode.cpp` but otherwise yes.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `std::string` knows how to deal with multiple repeated characters, so that `indent` function can be much simpler: `std::string Node::indent(int level) { std::string indt(level, '\t'); return indt; }`. Also, since it doesn't use any data from the class `Node`, it should probably be a **static** member function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override a function in a child class, you need to write the declaration in the class definition. The override specifier will only appear in the header file.

#### Header File

```
class FunctionNode : public DeclarationNode {
  FunctionNode(...) { ... }
  std::string toString(int level) const override; 
};
```

#### Source File

```
#include "FunctionNode.hpp"

std::string FunctionNode::toString(int level) const {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It has fixed my issue, but now it is saying:    'this' argument to member function 'indent' has type 'const FunctionNode', but function is not marked const
    std::string indt = indent(level);

Comment: Sure. `toString()` is a const method. You can't call non-const member functions like `indent` from a const method.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has no `return` statement for the method `Node::toString`. Other than that there doesn't seem to by any other error except

> fatal error: TypeNode.hpp: No such file or directory

since you didn't provide `TypeNode.hpp` in your original question.

The program **don't** have the error you mentioned as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/mkzRQj4Tg). If you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question, it will be good. Note `FunctionNode::toString` has also been declared inside the `FunctionNode` class in the above link.